# How can you pass in an actual method as a parameter to another method in Java?

Tags: java, generics, methods

What I want to do is to easily pass in an actual method object to another method.  This is so I can create a generic Joiner function that joins on a given method of a list of objects without the danger of just passing in a string that represents the method.  Is this possible in Java so that I can have syntax like:

```
joinOnMethod(String, Collections<T>, Method) e.g. 
joinOnMethod(", ", someList, T.getName())
```

Where T.getName() passes the getName() method into be called on each object in the list instead of passing in the return type of the method itself.

Hope this is clear enough for my needs,

Alexei Blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no first-class function support in Java directly. Two options:

- Pass in the name of the method, and use reflection to get at it
- Create a type with a single member, like this:

  ```
  public interface Function<In, Out> {
      Out apply(In input);
  }
  ```

  Then you can use an anonymous inner class, like this:

  ```
  joinOnMethod(", ", someList, new Function<T, String>() {
                   @Override public String apply(T input) {
                       return input.getName();
                   }
               });
  ```

  Of course you can extract that function as a variable:

  ```
  private static Function<T, String> NAME_EXTRACTOR = 
      new Function<T, String>() {
          @Override public String apply(T input) {
              return input.getName();
          }
      };

  ...

  joinOnMethod(", ", someList, NAME_EXTRACTOR);
  ```

Comment: Excellent answer Jon (you seem to answer all my Java questions ^.^).  This would be great but I'd end up creating thousands of these for each method as the code base is huge lol.  I hope Java puts some support in for this at some point :)

Comment: @AlexeiBlue: Java 8 will have more support for this, but I suspect you'll find you won't *really* need this as much as you might think. A few well chosen, commonly-accessible read-only fields exposing such functions may help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest researching the command pattern in Java. It supports callback functionality.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Java

Comment: Right... while other languages have *function pointers* or *delegates*, Java handles this through implementation of an interface.

Comment: I would rather deal with interfaces than C's function pointers. What a nightmare. Delegates are somewhat better.

Comment: I'm sorry you had a bad experience with function pointers.  An interface is nothing but a table of function pointers.  If you need a whole bunch of methods, the language support is nice.  But for single functions, having to define an interface and then a class implementing it is just clunky.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Once I was figuring out a stack corruption problem for a week since the third-party package developer did not notify us of a function change, so the pointer was now wrong and it was always overwriting the stack (without any errors obviously).

Comment: Sounds like a problem with a dangerous and unnecessary cast, not with the function pointer.  There's only one place where a cast should ever be used on a function pointer: the return value from `GetProcAddress` (Windows) and `dlsym` (Posix).

Comment: Excellent answer, I should have known about this pattern lol...  In  this case it would be extremely tedious to add structures in for every attribute in every data class.  I'll probably have to stick with reflection for now :)

Comment: @Ben Voight, forgot to mention that. You're right, it was GetProcAddress.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you've just moved to Java from Javascript or some other language that treats functions as objects.  To my knowledge, this isn't possible, as Java does not treat functions as objects.  You'll have to actually write it out in a `for` loop or some other construct.

Comment: No I haven't just moved from Javascript lol, I'm just a bit of a noobie with these concepts but thank you for the answer anyway :)

Comment: No problem.  I moved from Java to Javascript, and the idea of passing functions as parameters blew me away.  Don't forget to +1 an answer if it helped, even if you didn't accept it.

Comment: Not a problem +1'd indeed ^.^

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no syntax like that. Moreover, because of *type erasure*, the actual type `T` is not available at runtime, so it wouldn't be possible inside a generic even if the syntax were available.

The trick is to pass `Class<T>` along with other parameters, and use reflection to get the method:

```
joinOnMethod(String separator, Collections<T> items, String methodName, Class<T> theClass)
```

Now you can query the class for the method `methodName`, and use that method in the calculations. This does not help you get away from passing strings (i.e. the compiler wouldn't trigger an error when the method does not exist) but you can make it work with generics in spite of type erasure.

Comment: That's the bit I wanted to avoid unfortunately i.e. passing in the method name as a String.  It can be hazardous when using reflection and you change the name in the class as refactory tools don't pick this up :/  I'll have to think of something clever for this one :)